# Linq to XML: Finding value of a specific element

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I am new bee to "Linq" and "Linq to XML" concepts. I have the following xml tree

```
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
<name>IWS</name>
<SSIDConfig>
  <SSID>
    <hex>496153</hex>
    <name>ISL</name>
  </SSID>
</SSIDConfig>
<connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
<MSM>
  <security>
    <authEncryption>
      <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
      <encryption>AES</encryption>
      <useOneX>false</useOneX>
    </authEncryption>
    <sharedKey>
      <keyType>networkKey</keyType>
      <protected>false</protected>  
      <keyMaterial>BFEBBEA9B0E78ECD671A8D35D96556A32E001B7524A1</keyMaterial>
   </sharedKey>
 </security>
</MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

I was wondering how to retrieve the KeyMaterial element value using linq to xml?

I have tried to use the following code, but I get empty enumeration

```
var networkKey = from c in doc.Descendants("WLANProfile")
                 select (string)c.Element("keyMaterial").Value;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1.) `keyMaterial` is not a direct child of `WLANProfile` that's why you don't get any results (c.Elements will only look for a direct child)

2.) you need to use the specified namespace in the XML - otherwise no node will match

Both applied:

```
XNamespace xns = "http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1";
var networkKey = (from c in doc.Descendants(xns + "keyMaterial")
                  select (string)c.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Somewhat shorter in dot notation if you know there is always going to be exactly one key:

```
string networkKey = xdoc.Descendants(xns + "keyMaterial").Single().Value;
```